# Itext to update PDF form with multiple fields with same Field Name

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a requirement where i have to populate values in a PDF Form using Itext.

the Form i have has multiple fields with the same field names.
The Concept is to populate same value in case the PDF form field name is common.

so if there is are 2 or more fields with the name txtSysTime, then the code should fill the system time in all the fields.

My question is basically

1. Is this kind of functionality supported at all by Itext?
2. If it is Possible then how can we do the same.

I am using the below code for attempting the same:

```
PdfReader pdfTemplate = new PdfReader(inputFilePath);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfTemplate, fileOutputStream);
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
stamper.getAcroFields().setField("TextBox", "value filled");
```

With this code the value in the first field with the same name is populated correctly but the rest of it is left blank.

Please help

Answer (score -4, accepted):

PDF forms does not support 2 fields with the same name. requirement is invalid

Comment: This of course is false. Cf. section 12.7.3.2 Field Names [the PDF specification ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf): *It is possible for different field dictionaries to have the same fully qualified field name*... and the case mentioned there is not the only case.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want to do is use the 'autofill' functionality of pdf form fields? So you fill one field and all other fields with that fieldname are automatically filled with the same content. **That is perfectly possible.** (You probably tried that in adobe reader / acrobat)

But what you must differentiate (technically): Those formfields have one "data" representation and several widgets (several visual representations). Thus what you only need to do is fill that one field (which has several coordinates for its widgets) with a certain value:

```
boolean successful = stamper.getAcroFields().setField("TextBox", "some value");
```

If you then open that PDF in a PDF viewer software (like adobe reader) all fields have the same content. Out of curiosity why do you flatten the fields with `setFormFlattening(true)`? Then all your fields will be removed and flattened.

Answer (score 0):

itext is using widget annotation, for multiple field with same name..means for duplicate field , name will one but co ordinate will be multiple.

bellow code will help you..

```
 InputStream pdfFileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFileStream);
        PdfStamper stamper = null;

        try {
            stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, tempOS, '\0');

        } catch (DocumentException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
        Object[] keys = form.getFields().keySet().toArray();

        for (Entry<String, AcroFields.Item> entry : fields.entrySet()) {

        String docFieldName = entry.getKey();
            List<FieldPosition> fieldPosition = form.getFieldPositions(docFieldName); // for multiple filed with same name  size and co ordinate  will more then 1..
            for(int i=0;i<fieldPosition.size();i++) {
            Rectangle position = fieldPosition.get(i).position;
            float left = position.getLeft();
            float top = position.getTop();
            float width = position.getWidth();
            float height = position.getHeight();
            int currentPage = fieldPosition.get(i).page;
            ........................here you can set value to list..

            }


        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually you **can** have several fields with the same name inside one only pdf form, as long as the fields are on separate pages.
I'm currently looking for a solution for this problem...

Comment: It is nonsense that those fields have to be on different pages