# Is it possible to have multiple fields with same name, but with different styling properties

Tags: itext, field

We have a requirement to add multiple fields with same name in a form.
e.g signature, buyer_name.

As of now, we got this done using 'PdfWidgetAnnotation' from itext library. However, with this approach we have a single field backing multiple views, resulting in any change in field properties, e.g font styling bold, getting applied across all field occurrences with the same name. The requirement is to be able to apply different properties across the fields which share the same name.

Is there a way to do this using itext library, can you please help me with any pointers in this regard. Thanks for your time!

Itext library used: 7.1.10

**Sample code:**

```java
private void addFormFieldsWithSameName(PdfDocument pdfDocument, PdfAcroForm form, List<PdfAnnotationFields> fieldsToAdd) throws IOException {

    PdfAnnotationFields firstField = fieldsToAdd.get(0);
    PdfTextFormField formField = PdfTextFormField.createText(pdfDocument);
    setFormFieldProperties(formField, firstField);

    log.debug("Form field adding to pdf is: {} ", formField.toString());
    form.addField(formField, pdfDocument.getPage(firstField.getPageNumber()));

    for (PdfAnnotationFields fieldToAdd : fieldsToAdd) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(fieldToAdd.getLowerLeftXCords(), fieldToAdd.getLowerLeftYCords(),
                fieldToAdd.getWidth(), fieldToAdd.getHeight());
        PdfWidgetAnnotation pdfWidgetAnnotation = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(rectangle);
        pdfWidgetAnnotation.setVisibility(firstField.getVisibility());
        pdfDocument.getPage(fieldToAdd.getPageNumber()).addAnnotation(pdfWidgetAnnotation);
        formField.addKid(pdfWidgetAnnotation);
    }
}

private void setFormFieldProperties(PdfTextFormField formField, PdfAnnotationFields firstField) throws IOException {

    formField.setFieldName(firstField.getKey());
    formField.setMappingName(firstField.getMappingName());
    String fieldValue = annotationField.getDefaultValue() != null ? firstField.getDefaultValue() : ANNOTATION_DEFAULT_VALUE;
    formField.setDefaultValue(new PdfString(fieldValue));
    formField.setValue(fieldValue);
    formField.setPage(firstField.getPageNumber());
    formField.setReadOnly(firstField.isReadOnly());
    formField.setRequired(firstField.isRequired());
    formField.setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(firstField.getFontType().getFontTypeAlias()));
    formField.setFontSize(firstField.getFontSize());
    formField.setColor(Color.convertRgbToCmyk(new DeviceRgb(java.awt.Color.decode(firstField.getTextColor()))));
    formField.setJustification(firstField.getJustification());
}
```

**References used:**

[Itext to update PDF form with multiple fields with same Field Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951685/itext-to-update-pdf-form-with-multiple-fields-with-same-field-name)

[Itext 7, can't use two widgets referencing same form value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40383508/itext-7-cant-use-two-widgets-referencing-same-form-value)

Comment: The iText forms API assumes the same field-type-specific styling (e.g. the font of text fields) of all representations of a field. Only the generic widget annotation styling (e.g. borders) can be changed on the widget level. For more flexibility with iText you need to use its low level APIs and build the structures in question yourself.

Comment: Additionally a signature field is not such a good example since it is supposed to have only one widget representation (at least starting from PDF 2.0). It is certainly possible to style each (textfield, checkbox, radiobutton, drop-down box etc.) widget individually. For styling options have a look in the PDF spec (table 'annotation dictionaries'). Keys would be e.g. `C, IC, Border, BS, BE, BM, CA, ca, H, DA, Q, DS,...`

Comment: Thanks for your response @mkl I will check this possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Lonzak Not sure I understand well. What I meant is to be able to have different styling e.g Bold text for different instances of the fields sharing same name (not styling for each different type of widget)

Comment: You want something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/fHb8jAx.png)? So one "data" field with different styled widget annotations?

Comment: @Lonzak Functionally yes, this is what we need. Multiple fields with same name, but with different styling. I tried it with widget annotation, where i could have multiple fields with same name (views actually) but the styling now is shared across all these fields, but we want to be able to have individual styling and not shared.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to check.